# I need transform from XML List-Item to Indesign xml code

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I need transform from XML to Indesign xml code. Kindly advice anyone know the answer.

Input XML

```
<root>
<p><list list-type="order">
<list-item><p>This is quick.</p></list-item>
<list-item><p>Sivakumar Given and the fact that
   <list list-type="bullet">
   <list-item><p>This is sublist</p></list-item>
   <list-item><p>This is sub middle list</p></list-item>
   <list-item><p>This is sub last list</p></list-item>
   </list>
</p></list-item>
<list-item><p>We are now left with four remaining parameters:</p></list-item>
<list-item><p>Given and the fact that</p></list-item>
<list-item><p>In Section we obtained an estimate for the mean of.</p></list-item>
<list-item><p>From steps 3, 4, and 5 above, we have generated (a table of) values for.</p></list-item>
</list></p>
</root>
```

Required Output

```
<root>
<p><list list-type="order">
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-First"><p>This is quick.</p></list-item>
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle"><p>Sivakumar Given and the fact that
   <list list-type="bullet">
   <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-First"><p>This is sublist</p></list-item>
   <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-Middle"><p>This is sub middle list</p></list-item>
   <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-Last"><p>This is sub last list</p></list-item>
   </list>
</p></list-item>
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle"><p>We are now left with four remaining parameters:</p></list-item>
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle"><p>Given and the fact that</p></list-item>
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle"><p>In Section we obtained an estimate for the mean of.</p></list-item>
<list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Last"><p>From steps 3, 4, and 5 above, we have generated (a table of) values for.</p></list-item>
</list></p>
```

Thanks
Sivakumar M.

Comment: My answer would be XSLT. Or XQuery. Or hand-written code using standard APIs for parsing/manipulating/serializing the XML. HOWEVER: Your proposed output is broken; you must provide a namespace binding for the `aid:` prefix if you want the document to be accepted by modern XML tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this stylesheet. Check if the namespace `xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0"` is the correct one for your version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

    <xsl:template match="list-item[../@list-type='order']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-attribute-to-list-item">
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Order'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list-item[../@list-type='bullet']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-attribute-to-list-item">
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'SubBullet'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="add-attribute-to-list-item">
        <xsl:param name="type"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($type,'-First')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($type,'-Last')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($type,'-Middle')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root><xsl:apply-templates select="root/p"/></root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0">
   <p>
      <list list-type="order">
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-First">
            <p>This is quick.</p>
         </list-item>
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle">
            <p>Sivakumar Given and the fact that
            <list list-type="bullet">
                  <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-First">
                     <p>This is sublist</p>
                  </list-item>
                  <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-Middle">
                     <p>This is sub middle list</p>
                  </list-item>
                  <list-item aid:pstyle="SubBullet-Last">
                     <p>This is sub last list</p>
                  </list-item>
               </list>
            </p>
         </list-item>
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle">
            <p>We are now left with four remaining parameters:</p>
         </list-item>
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle">
            <p>Given and the fact that</p>
         </list-item>
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Middle">
            <p>In Section we obtained an estimate for the mean of.</p>
         </list-item>
         <list-item aid:pstyle="Order-Last">
            <p>From steps 3, 4, and 5 above, we have generated (a table of) values for.</p>
         </list-item>
      </list>
   </p>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi, Your answers is working fine and thank you so much!

Comment: @SivakumarM Please accept this answer (mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green). That is the polite way to say "thank you" on Stackoverflow.